# Is there any super global variable like asp application variable on php?

Tags: php, asp.net

is there anything like Application Variable in asp.net on PHP?

Its like a super global variable that every user can access the same variable although the internet browser is different.

Cause why I'm asking this is I need to make something like how much person is reading in this page at this moment or something like it.

Is there any like this on PHP? Or any tricks which I can use same as it?

Thanks for the attention :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP equivalent of ASP.NET Application/Cache objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740179/php-equivalent-of-asp-net-application-cache-objects)

Comment: As far as i know, no, there is no such superglobal, and i cant think of a proper workaround now. You could use a database, add a row, increase the value whenever a user logs in and decreases by one when a user logs out ... but that seems dirty to me.

Comment: If you looking for temporary persistence - it can be achieved by using cache or database

Comment: Aaaahh I got it, thanks for the link about  PHP equivalent of ASP.NET Application/Cache objects. Too bad I have to use database for make it look like a Super Global Variable.